# string and int concatenation resulting in null for a Tetris clone?

Tags: xna

I'm writing a tetris clone, and I have sprites (of every possible piece and rotation) loaded through the XNA content pipeline. For example, I have assets "i", "i2", "i3", and "i4" for each rotation of the 4-block-long I-tetrimino. For the O-tetrimino, I only have asset "o", because the O-tetrimino doesn't require any rotations.

I want to load each of these assets into a 2D array of `Texture2D`s. Here's my attempt:

```
1 Texture2D[,] tetriminoTextures = new Texture2D[7, 4];
2 char[] tetriminos = { 'o', 'i', 'l', 'j', 'z', 's', 't' };
3 string t;
4 
5 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
6 {
7     for (int j = 1; i <= 4; i++)
8     {
9         if (i == 0 || j == 1) // If char[i] == 'o', then don't consider rotations.
10                              // The square piece doesn't have rotations.
11                              // If j == 1, then leave the asset name as is.
12            t = letters[i].ToString();
13        else // (i != 0 && j <= 2 && j <= 4)
14            t = letters[i].ToString() + j;
15        tetriminoTextures[i, j-1] = Content.Load<Texture2D>(t);           
16    }    
17 }
```

However, when I attempt to

```
spriteBatch.Draw(tetriminoTextures[x, y], /* some position vector */, Color.White);
```

I get an `ArgumentNullException`. Apparently `tetriminoTextures[x, y]` is `null` when `y >= 1 && y <= 3`.

I have no idea what's going on. I think it may have something to do with my concatenating a `string` and an `int` together in line 14. But I'm getting an `ArgumentNullException` even when `i == 0 && j >= 2 && j <= 4` (i.e. for each rotation of the O-tetrimino excluding the first one), though the if statement in line 9 should have caught these cases. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the var i to j here

```
7 for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
8     {
9
```

Maybe you should use the step trace to debug your execution flow...  worth it... :)

Anyway is a common copy/paste bug... hehehe

Comment: Damn, I got owned by a for loop for the past 3 hours. Thanks for pointing that out! Also, I'll upvote when I can.